# Not lock up the GUI on thread.sleep

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'm writing a multiple user server\client application.

Essentially, it will implement a chat room and allow users to communicate with each other. I've gotten the application to work between the server\client so far by sending a request to the server, which is always checking for an incoming network connection, and responding to it immidiately.

However, for the client to receive chat messages from the server, the only thing I can think of is running a server on the client. If I were to do this, however, the client would freeze up and not be able to do anything. Plus, the client is not designed for opening ports to connect to the server.

What would be the best recommendation on waiting on data from the server to come to the client, without causing the client to lock up?

Thanks!

(and also, I'm not a \professional\ c# programmer, more of an amateur, so please don't give me very complicated answers)

Comment: If you want to avoid locking up the GUI you will have to do this work in a background thread which might be a bit more difficult than you're hoping.

Comment: `Plus the client is not designed for opening ports to connect to the server` - then it isn't a client. Your design sounds like it is heading down the wrong path. Can you explain your setup a bit more?

Comment: Basically, I need the client to connect to the server. The server will allow for port forwarding, but I do not want the clients to have to open their ports to work with the server. The client (a) needs to send chat to the server, and the server needs to respond to client a, b, and c that there was a message.

Comment: It is the kind of project that turns an amateur into a professional C# programmer.  With a lot less head hair, writing asynchronous code isn't that easy.  Lots and lots of google hits show you how to use BeginXxx methods of the Socket class, you don't really need us to add more hits.

Comment: @HansPassant async IO will turn a boy into a man, did I get that right, Hans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use either a background worker, or a second thread.  If you don't want to do that, you can use `thread.suspend`.

To start a new thread:

```
Using System.Threading;

Thread t = new Thread()
t.Start;
```

Note: this is not recommended.